# How to count the records from a txt file in perl

Tags: perl

I'm new in perl and I'm facing problem with counting the records in a file as my file is having different groups arranged serially and I want to put them into records starting from AC to // consisting of 1 record. Can you help me out..Thanks in advance...

Input File:

```
//
AC  T00001
FA  AAF
OS  human, Homo sapiens
//
AC  T00002
FA  ACE2
OS  yeast, Saccharomyces cerevisiae
SQ  MDNVVDPWYINPSGFAKDTQDEEYVQHHDNVNPTIPPPDNYILNNENDDGLDNLLGMDYY
//
AC  T00003
FA  AS-C T3
OS  fruit fly, Drosophila melanogaster
SQ  MTSICSSKFQQQHYQLTNSNIFLLQHQHHHQTQQHQLIAPKIPLGTSQLQNMQQSQQSNV
SQ  GPMLSSQKKKFNYNNMPYGEQLPSVARRNARERNRVKQVNNGFVNLRQHLPQTVVNSLSN
SQ  GGRGSSKKLSKVDTLRIAVEYIRGLQDMLDDGTASSTRHIYNSADESSNDGSSYNDYNDS
SQ  LDSSQQFLTGATQSAQSRSYHSASPTPSYSGSEISGGGYIKQELQEQDLKFDSFDSFSDE
SQ  QPDDEELLDYISSWQEQ
//
AC  T00004
FA  Sc
OS  fruit fly, Drosophila melanogaster
SQ  MKNNNNTTKSTTMSSSVLSTNETFPTTINSATKIFRYQHIMPAPSPLIPGGNQNQPAGTM
SQ  PIKTRKYTPRGMALTRCSESVSSLSPGSSPAPYNVDQSQSVQRRNARERNRVKQVNNSFA
SQ  RLRQHIPQSIITDLTKGGGRGPHKKISKVDTLRIAVEYIRSLQDLVDDLNGGSNIGANNA
//
```

Comment: Are you counting the SQs as records or are those separators?

Comment: What are you trying to count? And it sounds like you're trying to sort, too?

Comment: Ah, nice reformatting of the question.  So if you count the number of lines beginning with AC will that be an accurate count of the "number of records?"

Comment: Most probably you need to read it into array of hashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I get you want to create record having as ID the AC value and finishing by the // string.

The following script will get all the ids T**** and create a hash value for each of them.
The last line allow you to count how many records are in this hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @lines;
my %hash;
my $opId;

open my $input_fh, "<", 'so.input';
chomp(@lines = <$input_fh>);
close $input_fh;

foreach (@lines) {
    if (/(?<ctrl>.{2})(\s+)(?<value>.*)/) {
        if ($+{ctrl} eq 'AC') {
            $opId = $+{value};
        }   
        $hash{$opId}{$+{ctrl}} .= $+{value};
    }   
}

my @records = keys %hash;

print Dumper(%hash);
print @records . " records had been found on this file\n";
```

I hope it was what you asked,

Comment: The last line will print the list instead of the count, I think (you want either `scalar(@records)` or `$#records+1`).

Comment: Hi spredzy need your help...I wanted to know what is the function of this line...in your above given code if (/(?<ctrl>.{2})(\s+)(?<value>.*)/) Also the records that I am getting are so random that I am not able to figure them out as why they are not in a serial order like the output is somewhat...T03004 {'SQ' =>hjhvbdsvjd 'OS' => mouse 'FA' =. 'pax '//'}; T08079 { OS => kkjcs 'FA' => hbjhhj '//'}; could you please help me as I am not getting the number followed by T03004 and getting T08079 also the order which I am getting is the reverse of my input file.

Comment: e.g I am getting SQ...OS...FA and no AC as initial just the number followed by AC. instead of AC...FA...OS...SQ...MX

Comment: @soniya I updated the code so you can get now the AC. Just copy paste it. This line (/(?<ctrl>.{2})(\s+)(?<value>.*)/) is a regular expression matching operation. The ?<> allow me to name the desired part of the pattern. We are talking about hashes so "order" does not mean anything. You retrieve the data the way you want them.

Comment: Hey Spredzy, sorry for bothering again but there is a real serious problem with the code because of which it is not picking all the lines it is skipping several lines in between. Although it is fetching the data from AC to // but  some of the lines of 'SQ' are being skipped like above you can see in my input file 'SQ'has 4 or 5 lines so in my output I am getting may be just the first line of SQ and the last line, the lines in between are missing. And the same thing thing is happening with the whole data it is making hashes records with so many of them present in between them are being missed.

Comment: I am grateful to you for the help. I am trying to figure out the problem in code but unable to do. That is why asking you again. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to change the input record separator (see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)):

```
$/ = '//';
while (<>)
{
    # record is in $_, now do something with it...
}
```

**EDIT:** If your goal is merely to count the records, you could do something like...

```
my @lines = <>;
my @lines_with_ac = grep { /^AC/ } @lines;
my $number_of_records = scalar @lines_with_ac;
```

Comment: I want to put AC to // in a record and then want to check how many records are there in my file.Thanks all for help

Comment: @soniya: Use my first solution above, then, or @Flimzy's.

Comment: Changing the input record separator will also make `//` a meta character in the entire file, so if any record contains such, it will corrupt the database.

Answer (score 1):

This script will count how many `//`-terminated records exist in your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$/ = '//';
open FH, "/path/to/my/file";
my $count;
while (<FH>) {
    $count++;
}
close FH;
print "$count records\n";
```

Note that you might get a +1 error in this case, since your file *starts* with `//`--that means the first "record" it reads in will be empty.  If this is an issue, just subtract one from the final result.

Comment: Like I commented in Platinum's answer, this will make `//` a meta character in the entire file, and will cause corruptions if it exists anywhere else but at the end of a record.

Comment: Obviously a `//`-delimited file with `//`'s in places other than record separators will cause problems. If that occurs, I would consider that file, though, not in the parser. To help combat that, though, you might potentially set `$/ = "\n//\n".

Answer (score 1):

run it: perl script.pl inputfile

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @records;

my $i = 0;
while (<>)
{
  if (/^AC/../\/\//){
    chomp;
    /\/\// ? $i++ : push @{$records[$i]},$_;
  }
}

foreach (0 .. $#records){
  print "record", $_+1, ":\n\n";
  print Dumper $records[$_];
  print "\n\n"
}
```

Comment: The end of record character check should be `m{^\s*//\s*$}`, or something equally strict. To solve the question directly: `print scalar @records`.

Answer (score 0):

If your file was named test.data, type this on the commandline

```
cat test.dat | perl -ne 'print if /^AC/;' | wc -l
```

It prints the count of the number of lines beginning with AC.  This assumes that all records begin with AC and the term AC is used only as the beginning of the record.

You can also do this without perl at all:

```
cat test.dat | egrep "^AC" | wc -l
```

The commandline is a lot of fun.